Converting Intptr to size
I have an IntPtr that represents a memory address. Is there a simple way to determine the size of the bytes located at the memory address the IntPtr points to?
I have tried creating a loop, but it results in an access violation without producing the result.
EDIT: I do not have the bitmap. I have an IntPtr. Nowhere in my question do I ask about a bitmap.
Instead of returning as int, returned void and write to stream. Writes the data to file but still access violation even with a try/catch.
I can do this knowing the size but on the unknown Scan0 I can get a result but not without the access violation. If the access violation could be caught, I could predetermine the size.
public record struct MemoryPointer(IntPtr Scan0, int Size)
{
    public async Task Save(string filePath)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[Size];
        using Stream stream = File.Create(filePath);
        unsafe
        {
            byte* pointer = (byte*)Scan0;
            for (int index = 0; index < Size; index++, pointer++)
            {
                bytes[index] = *pointer;
            }
        }
        await stream.WriteAsync(bytes);
    }
}


No impossible, a pointer is just a pointer, you need to know what it represents yourself. Where did you get it?

@Charlieface it's the scan0 of a Bitmap

A pointer is just a pointer. It holds an address, but has no idea what is located at that address or how large it is, just like a letter addressed to your home has no idea what sort of structure it is or how many bedrooms and bathrooms it has inside. As far as what's causing your access violation, it's impossible to say without seeing your code.

@KenWhite i've updated. Thanks, I understand why i get the access violation. its because the requested size was too large. if done within a loop we could find the size if we could catch the access violation exception

It's a pretty simple calculation if you are coming off a bitmap, see link

@Charlieface I know that it came from a bitmap but I do not have the bitmap. if i did i would just take stride * height to get the size. this is dealing with the scan0 of a bitmap that I dont have access to.

The actual problem here is simply: passing the wrong Size - we can't help there, it is upstream to this code.
A pointer by itself, as discussed in the comments, is just the start location. You can't determine the size range from just a pointer (unless that is a pointer to a managed object with type metadata, which isn't the case here). There is a concept that defines what you want .NET - a "span". A span is effectively a managed pointer and the number of elements (bytes in your case) to be considered. If you switched your code to think in terms of spans rather than start/size pairs, it is often easier to keep track of what is happening.
The main reason I mention this, however, is because you're currently copying the data to a byte[] in order to use WriteAsync. There is a second WriteAsync approach that takes a ReadOnlyMemory<byte> argument. If you were using the synchronous Write API, then creating a span from a pointer and size is trivial, but for async we need an extra step and we need to know that a [ReadOnly]Memory<T> is simply an access for [ReadOnly]Span<T>, and then we can create a "memory" over our span and size using something like this.
To make a ong story short (too late!):
var mgr = new UnmanagedMemoryManager<byte>(Scan0, Size);
await stream.WriteAsync(mrg.Memory);

Ok modern runtimes this should completely avoid any additional copying. On down-level runtimes, it might use a leased array-poop buffer to copy the data, and use the old byte[] path, but a: you didn't have to write that copy and b: it will at least be leased rather than an allocation each time!

Thanks Marc, I looked into this and it works incredibly well. I was hoping there would be a way to get the size or atleast a way to catch the access violation exception. I've tried to use the [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions] attribute from another post which didn't seem to be of any help.

Access violations are pretty aggressive; I wouldn't expect to be able to survive something that pathologically wrong
